# ZFS: Backup a disk with mountpoints that conflict with backup computer?

Tags: backup, zfs, storage, mountpoint

I'm working towards backing up a laptop running Ubuntu on ZFS.  I have a backup server also running ZFS on some ancillary volumes (not the root).

I made a snapshot of `bpool` today and sent it to the backup server using `zfs send / recv` commands:

```
export SNAPSHOT=first-backup-2022-01-27
zfs snapshot -r bpool@$SNAPSHOT
zfs send -LRc bpool@$SNAPSHOT | pv | ssh root@192.168.1.45 zfs recv -F susepool0/sets/1M/os-images/Ubuntu-thinkpad-t460s/bpool@$SNAPSHOT
```

This works fine for the first backup, but when I went to the server where the backups will be stored, the mountpoint is still set to `/boot`:

```
zfs list | grep t460s
susepool0/sets/1M/os-images/Ubuntu-thinkpad-t460s/bpool@first-backup-2022-01-27                      591M  3.83T       96K  /boot
susepool0/sets/1M/os-images/Ubuntu-thinkpad-t460s/bpool/BOOT@first-backup-2022-01-27                 591M  3.83T       96K  none
susepool0/sets/1M/os-images/Ubuntu-thinkpad-t460s/bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_qjvcro@first-backup-2022-01-27   591M  3.83T      162M  /boot
```

How can I best configure this backup so its mountpoints don't conflict with the server they will be stored on?  The `rpool` has everything, like `/usr`, `/var`, `/etc` - I could see that being a real mess if those were allowed to re-mount remotely.

Edit:  Someone asked me to post the ZFS mountpoints on the source and destination because they thought it might be helpful, so I am happy to oblige:

Edit edit (1-30-2021):  I was asked to make these lists less voluminous, so these lists only include the most pertinent filesystem mounts to demonstrate what I'm saying about how the zfs mountpoints will conflict with the unix file paths if a snapshot image is sent containing the same mounts

I'm thinking a possible solution could be to set an alternate root for the snapshots, either before or after the snapshot is sent, but I am not sure how to do that or what command would be responsible.

Client (source) - This is the machine running ZFS root (Ubuntu 21.10):

```
❯ for i in bpool rpool/ROOT; do echo ' '; zfs list -t filesystem -o name,mountpoint -d 4 $i; done

NAME                      MOUNTPOINT
bpool                     /boot
bpool/BOOT                none
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_qjvcro  /boot

NAME                                              MOUNTPOINT
rpool/ROOT                                        none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro                          /
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/srv                      /srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/usr                      /usr
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/usr/local                /usr/local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var                      /var
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var/games                /var/games
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var/lib                  /var/lib
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var/lib/AccountsService  /var/lib/AccountsService
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var/lib/NetworkManager   /var/lib/NetworkManager
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var/lib/apt              /var/lib/apt
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var/lib/dpkg             /var/lib/dpkg
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var/lib/machines         /var/lib/machines
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var/log                  /var/log
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var/mail                 /var/mail
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var/snap                 /var/snap
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var/spool                /var/spool
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var/www                  /var/www
```

Server (destination) - note, this machine uses btrfs for its root filesystem, but that doesn't mean a if `rpool/ROOT` tries to mount to `/` it won't be a problem:

```
❯ ssh osuse-leap zfs list -t filesystem,volume -o name,mountpoint -d 2
NAME                                  MOUNTPOINT
susepool0                             /mnt/susepool0
susepool0/sets                        /mnt/susepool0/sets
susepool0/sets/16K                    /mnt/susepool0/sets/16K
susepool0/sets/1M                     /mnt/susepool0/sets/1M
susepool0/sets/4K                     /mnt/susepool0/sets/4K
susepool0/sets/64K                    /mnt/susepool0/sets/64K
susepool0/sets/chipmunk-user-folder   /mnt/ubuntu/home/avery
susepool0/snapper-backup              /mnt/snapper
susepool0/snapper-backup/vols         /mnt/snapper/vols
susepool0/vols                        /mnt/susepool0/vols
susepool0/vols/endpoint-bob-image     -
susepool0/vols/macosvol0              -
susepool0/vols/real-endpoint-bob      -
susepool0/vols/testvol                -
susepool0/vols/vmfspool0              -
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `zfs list -ro name,mountpoint rpool` for both source and dest?

Comment: @freezed sure thing, updated OP.

Comment: OK, thanks. But please try to be as concise as possible: suggested commands limits output to usefull data: size information harden reading and understanding. Here I am not on a wide screen to get all data without scrolling… I'll give my answer later when I can read

Comment: @freezed you got it, good suggestion.  Please see revised.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I have no knowledge in `BTFS` and I cannot say if sending `ZFS` snapshots on it works transparently. This could lead to your issue.

Secondly, about `ZFS` *mount related* [properties](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/zfsprops.8.html):

- `mountpoint` can use inheritance
- `canmount` manage if a pool is mounted by default
- `overlay` manage the case when a mountpoint exists before mount

In your case, I do not understand what are your source/destination dataset and I cannot see a dataset used as *parent* on destination.
If you send `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro`, it will be mounted on `/` on dest.

You can combine properties above to avoid mounting on `/`

But a more clever way will be using child datasets…

- `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/srv`
- `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/var/www`
- etc.

…to a *destination dataset* with a mountpoint properly set:

- `susepool0/backup/qjvcro` with `mountpoint=/mnt/backup/qjvcro/` (for instance)

In this case, a source like `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_qjvcro/srv` will be mounted on dest to `/mnt/backup/qjvcro/srv`